# Is Google PageSpeed Insights linking to SO for support incorrectly?

Tags: discussion, scope, product-support

Google's [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) asks users to use Stack Overflow for support.

Should it be suggesting using [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) instead?

Comment: [Signs point to yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhZBA.jpg). I guess the argument would be that Google PageSpeed Insights is a tool primarily used by programmers, but I'm not sure that's even true. Search-engine optimization is outside of Stack Overflow's scope. Google's own page that you linked to is not sufficiently descriptive of their own product for me to be able to tell exactly what it does, unfortunately.